# Django access queryset variabile from a custom method on the same view

Tags: django-views

I am implementing csv export on django. In particular I have a link on my template to export actual query and for this I am trying to handle all on the same class based view.

Here is my code

```
# views.py  
class MyView(ListView):  
    template_name = 'my_template.html'  
    model = Archivio  

    def get_queryset(self):

        if self.request.GET.get('q'):  
            dateC = '01/01/'+self.request.GET.get('q')          
            queryset = Archivio.objects.filter(~Q(quoteiscrizione__anno_quota__exact=self.request.GET.get('q'))  
            return queryset

    # my custom method
    @staticmethod  
    def csv_output():  
        qs = MyView.get_queryset(): # i want to access to the queryset variable from get_queryset() method of the class  
        # here i have other code to produce csv output
```

But the method csv_output() is wrong.. I get this TypeError: csv_output() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I have also tried with a classmethod decorator but without success.

My question is: How can i access queryset variable from another method of the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Issue saving my queryset on the request and then using it somewhere on my views like this:

```
views.py
class SomeClass(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        .....
        queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(*somefilterlist)
        self.request.session['search_queryset'] = serialize('json', queryset) # in order to save something on session in must be JSON serialized

class Output(SomeClass):
    @classmethod
    def cvsOutput(cls):
        deserialized = list(deserialize('json', request.session.get('search_queryset')))
        pk_list = []
        for arch in deserialized:
            pk_list.append(arch.object.pk) # List of pk

        queryset = Archivio.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list) # Query the list ok pk's
```

In this way I was able to make available the list ok pk of the queryset of my ListView, then I make again the same query based on that list of pk's..

Answer (score 0):

Note the `self` in `get_queryset(self)`. It means the first argument of this method is always the instance of the class (in your case, `MyView`). So when you want to call it in another method, you should provide this instance.

The solution is to replace your `@staticmethod` decorator with the `@classmethod` one:

```
class MyView(ListView):  
    template_name = 'my_template.html'  
    model = Archivio  

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.GET.get('q'):  
            dateC = '01/01/' + self.request.GET.get('q')          
            queryset = Archivio.objects.filter(~Q(quoteiscrizione__anno_quota__exact=self.request.GET.get('q'))  

            return queryset

    @classmethod  
    def csv_output(cls):
        qs = cls.get_queryset(cls)

        # Class methods have one required positional argument
        # which is the class that contains them

        # They are called like this:
        # MyClass.class_method()

        # So in your case, you can call
        # get_queryset() by doing MyView.get_queryset()

        # But as you are in a class method, you do
        # cls.get_queryset()

        # As get_queryset() needs one positional argument *self*,
        # which is the instance of your class, you do
        # cls.get_queryset(cls)

        # and it will work as expected :-)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. i changed my code as you suggested but i am getting a
TypeError csv_output() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Can you show me where and how you call `csv_output()` ?

Comment: I am calling it from my urls.py in this way url (r'somedir/ $', views.MyView.csv_output, name='somename')
As you see i am trying to use that function as a view :)

Comment: Try `views.MyView.as_view().csv_output()`

Comment: In this way i get an AttributeError 'function' object has no attribute csv_output!

Comment: I have another class on my views.py where i have a classmethod and i pass cls and request as second argument and it works fine, if i try to do the same thing in this other class (passing request as second parameter) i got an AttributeError but this time on get_queryset method like type object 'MyView' has no attribute 'request' on the line where i have 'if request.GET.get('q')'

Comment: Last update: On views.py I did 'def csv_output(cls)' and on urls.py i did 'views.MyView.csv_output()' and i get an type object 'MyView' has no attribute 'request' this time on get_queryset method..

Comment: The solution that I am thinking of now is to make `csv_output()` a function-based separate view and access `MyView().get_queryset()` in it, like this: `def csv_output(request): qs = MyView().get_queryset()`. And in your `urls.py` you map it like this: `url(r'...', views.csv_output, name='...')`

Comment: That's a nice idea! but i get  an AttributeError 'MyView' object has no attribute 'request' from this part: 'if self.request.GET.get('q'):' from my get_queryset function. However I do not want to execute that funcion, I just would like to access to a variable that already exist and that belongs to the instance of that class that is created when i Execute my view from urls. In fact, the problem is that our tests are executing again get_queryset and, of course, it will lack of 'request' parameter.